# Retrieve results of query inside for loop

Tags: soql

Trying to retrieve the results from query to map inside JSONgenerator but not sure how to link my results of query to the map inside for loop. Please look into my code below and suggest where I am getting this wrong. Thanks

```
Map<Id, Case> cMap = new Map<Id, Case>([Select Id, accountId From Case Where ID IN :caseIds]);

list<Id> assetAccounts = new list<Id>();

JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

for(Id c: CaseIds) {
   gen.writeStartObject();
   if(caseMap.get(c).accountId != null) {
      assetAccounts.add(caseMap.get(caseId).accountId);
      Map<Id, string> phoneNos = new Map<Id, string>();
   }
   gen.writeEndObject();
}
system.debug(gen.getAsString());
for (Asset asset : [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Asset WHERE AccountId IN :assetAccounts]) {
        if(asset.Description == 'TN'){
            phoneNos.add(asset.id, asset.SerialNumber);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Goki mentioned, the variable `c` is a case ID and not a case object. If you want to put the case ID in the JSON string you can do this:

```
for(Id c: CaseIds) 
{  
   gen.writeStartObject();
   gen.writeStringField('caseId', c);  
   gen.writeEndObject();
}
```

Comment: Bachovski, I forgot to edit if condition while pasting here. Corrected it now. Can you suggest how to get the values of asset query (phoneNos) inside JSON as I am getting error "variable doesnot exist: phoneNos". Thanks

Comment: Move this line `Map<Id, string> phoneNos = new Map<Id, string>();` before the for loop.

Comment: @pmvsdt Guess you should compile your code and see the errors first. You have declared phoneNos in first for loop and accessing it in second for loop. This will throw error variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Goki, As Bachovski suggested I made a mistake by writing map<....> = new map<...> inside my for loop. Moving that outside for loop resolved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess the the variable c in for loop is just an Id, but you are referencing it to get an accountId. That is wrong.

Comment: Hi Goki, corrected the code now. I incorrectly pasted the if condition initially

Answer (score 2):

You don't really explain what you are trying to get into the JSON. But I suggest that [JSONGenerator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsongenerator.htm) is best reserved for when you want very detailed control of the conversion to Apex. Generally it is much easier to put the data in maps and lists either with or without simple Apex classes whose fields represent the types and names. Then when something changes, you typically won't have to change the serialisation code.

See [JSON.serialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_serialize) and [JSON2apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Hi Keith, I am using JSON to post these values to a web service. Your reference links and suggestions are definitely helpful for me. Thanks for posting them.